# route url breaks page layout MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a page which corresponds to the route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Claims", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{year}/{divid}");
```

However, when it displays it breaks the layout of the master page it's attached to. I have tried to empty the page, the master page layout is still deformed.

For your information: I have noticed that references to static files are represented in the view source of the defective page as:

```
href="../../../../Content/site.css"
```

Where as in the normal ( correctly displayed ) pages they are represented as:

```
href="../Content/site.css"
```

Any help Please, ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using some sort of server side relative markup for these, thus when you're further in the site it tries to append more ../

I would use just a static line of HTML for these. There's rarely a reason to have css and javascript in deeper folders in your site (especially as with MVC there aren't "folders" representing these urls anyway) so just put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/site.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would use the url helper in its place....

For WebForms View:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<%: Url.Content("~/Content/site.css") %>' />`

For Razor View:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='@Url.Content("~/Content/site.css")' />`

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I preferred to simply use the static code  as suggested by Chao.